# IBMid SoftLayer linked user password automated reset

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

My question is basically the same as this question [SoftLayer API OpenIdConnect Reset Password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40872929/softlayer-api-openidconnect-reset-password).

Once SoftLayer users are linked to IBM Bluemix users, the softlayer API can no longer be used to reset user passwords.

The only answer to the previous question indicates that "a bluemix api" must be used.

I've been searching for such an api but I'm not finding much, a million links for API design and connect on Bluemix but nothing for resetting the password in an automated fashion.

Can anyone point me to an API can can be used to reset or change the password for SoftLayer IBMid linked users?

Thanks!

Update:
I continue to search for a solution, I've downloaded and installed the BlueMix CLI and the Cloud Foundry CLI cf.

The bluemix CLI doesn't seem to have any password functionality, cf has a user password function but after prompting for Current Password and New and Confirm, it reports that current password doesn't match, which leads me to believe that the CF user functions are not tied to the IBMid open id server. (makes sense, just wanted to make sure and rule it out as an option)

Comment: I've never performed a password reset via API, but I know Cloud Foundry (and inherently, Bluemix) uses UAA as their accounts and authentication system. Here's something that might relate to what you need: 
https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/api/uaa/#request-reset-password-code

Comment: Thank you @NaN, for the info and the link! I will look into it and post my results.